# Creating a generic property in a Map object in Dart

Tags: dart

I have this map:

```
final x = {
  "y": {},
  "z": {},
}
```

I want the $y property to hold an object with the type of $e inside of a property of type integer i.e:

```
x = {
  "y": {
    1: {/*e*/},
    2: {/*e*/},
    3: {/*e*/},
  }
}
```

While I want the $z property to to hold $g instead of $e, just like $y, but I want it to hold $g and not $e, i.e:

```
x = {
  "y": {
    1: {/*e*/},
    2: {/*e*/},
    3: {/*e*/},
  },
  "z": {
    1: {/*g*/},
    2: {/*g*/},
    3: {/*g*/},
  }
}
```

I've tried the following:

```
final x = {
  Map<int, e> "y": {},
  Map<int, g> "z": {},
}
```

This didn't work.

I also tried:

```
x = {
  "y": {
    1: Map<e>,
  },
  "z": {
    1: Map<g>,
  }
}
```

Also that didn't work,

- Note that $x, and $g are objects (instances) created by a class.
- When I say "This didn't work" I mean, it's showing an error.

How can I do that in Dart?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I'm understanding your question correctly, but I think you're looking for something like:

```dart
class E {}

class G {}

void main() {
  var e = E();
  var g = G();

  var x = <String, Map>{
    "y": <int, E>{
      1: e,
      2: e,
      3: e,
    },
    "z": <int, G>{
      1: g,
      2: g,
      3: g,
    }
  };
}
```

In general, you specify types for *variables*, and you can specify types when instantiating generics (`<K, V>{}` constructs a `Map<K, V>` literal).  Note that type-checking will necessarily occur at runtime and cannot be statically performed at compilation-time.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
abstract class MyClass {}

class ClassA extends MyClass {
  int propI;
  String propS;
}

class ClassB extends MyClass {
  bool propB;
  num propN;
}

main(List<String> args) {
  final keys1 = List<String>.from(['y','z']);
  final keys2 = List<int>.generate(3, (i) => i+1);
  final x = Map<String, Map<int, MyClass>>.fromIterables(
    keys1, 
    List<Map<int, MyClass>>.generate(keys1.length, (i) => Map<int, MyClass>.fromIterables(
      keys2, 
      List<MyClass>.generate(keys2.length, (j) => i == 0 ? ClassA() : ClassB())
    ))
  );

  print(x.toString());
  print(x.runtimeType.toString());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't.  The best you can do is dynamic if you can't tie down the types more than that.  The freezed package can do some sort of union types with build-time code manipulation.